# How to pass C# string variable to .BAT file from Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, string, forms, batch-file

I want to apologize in advance, as this question may already be answered elsewhere(can't find the specific answer).  I have searched extensively and it is making my more and more confused.  At this point I figured I could get an easy quick answer to my specific question/dilemma.

I have a C# Windows Form App.  I am doing my testing with a textbox and a button.  I would like the user to enter a 3-digit number into the textbox and click the button to save the 3-digit user input as a string value, then launch a pre-determined .BAT file.  I then would like to have the input GOTO *string* executed by my .BAT file. Here is what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ComboBoxAndButton
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.textBox1.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(textBox1_KeyPress);
    }
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
     {
        e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar);
     }

    public string opconumber;

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      opconumber = textBox1.Text;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Start();
    }

   private void Start() 
   {
       System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
       proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\mybat.bat";
//I am guessing that i need my string inserted somewhere in here.
       proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
       proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
       proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
       proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
       proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
       proc.Start();
       proc.WaitForExit();
       this.Close();
   }  
   }
}
```

One other thing I had an issue with is getting the backspace key to work.  I tried a few different snippets and couldn't get it right.  Any pointers or criticism is openly accepted.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

OK. I have a batch file i would like to skip to a particular label. i would like the string variable i saved to act as the determining factor of what is executed in the bat file. here is an example:

```
@echo off 
:111 ECHO Argument 111 
goto end 
:112 ECHO Argument 112 
goto end 
:end 
pause
```

How can i get the bat to start at :112 by using the string "112" when launching the bat?

Comment: What do you mean by "pass" it to the bat? I guess you are looking for parameters when executing a bat file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = " my arguments";
```

Comment: these would actually become 2 separate arguments; my and arguments

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer that's why `my arguments` is in its plural form ;)

Comment: :) nice, I just thought it can catch a person off guard

Answer (score 1):

Add it as an argument:

```
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = opconumber ;
```

In the bat file you can get this via %1.

Whoops too slow...

Comment: I understand the argument concept using %1 %2 etc, but i will have roughly 200 different arguments, and the %1 %2 method only uses the first digit, hence i need to use the three digit number, as i will have 200+ labels within the bat that i would have to jump to upon launch.  sorry for not explaining that.  am i missing something?

Comment: I was trying to use the argument %1 %2 method but the shift command seems very confusing when dealing with the number of different labels i will have in my bat file.

Answer (score 0):

In Batch you can use the `shift` command to access more than 9 arguments:

```
@echo off &setlocal
:start
echo %~1
shift /1
if "%~1" neq "" goto :start

endlocal
```